# Rails public/private key authentication, but user has no server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I've built a JavaScript app that's powered by a Rails back-end.  The JavaScript app (the built/minified version) is going to live on an S3 bucket.

The app Iv'e built is going to run on other people's websites, similar to Stripe (Stripe has you include this code in your HTML):

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="api_key"
    data-amount="999"
    data-name="Stripe.com"
    data-description="Widget"
    data-image="/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
```

The difference is that my user will have no back-end, it's all handled by my Rails API.  The end-user fills out the form on my user's website, and that data is POSTed to my API, not my user's API.  My user signs up, posts a snippet with a script to my JavaScript app on their website, and then they have users fill out a form (again, like Stripe) on their website which sends a request to my API.

How can I manage authentication in this circumstance?  The key that will be provided in the code snippet is obviously public, given that it's in the HTML on my user's website.  How can I verify the request is coming from the correct person given the key?  Should I look at IP Address and/or domain name that the request comes from?

Comment: hmm interesting, if you looked at the API's we use(example the facebook API, Pusher API , etc) maybe you can find some open source one and see how ? even closed source projects would give you an idea on how to manage this

Comment: Most of these APIs we setup a pusher, stripe, or facebook instance on the server-side with the private/secret/server key.  My user has no server.

Comment: hmm you mean your user wants to consume the API from example mobile app ? desktop app ?

Comment: I mean my user signs up and posts a snippet like in the OP on their website.  Then *their* users fill out a form triggered by a button that opens a modal (like Stripe), and when *their* user fills out the form it sends a request to my app's API.  The problem is that I need to authenticate the person (which is my user) posting this snippet on their website, how can I achieve this?

Comment: ok, in the end your user is a developer who wants to use your API for his/her users(be it in form,after sign up , whatever).
is the html form going to be included in a mobile app ? desktop app ?

Comment: The user isn't a developer, they're actually not technical at all.  They won't ever interact with the API directly, but they'll post my snippet on their website.  Then their users that go to their website will fill out the form (that is triggered from a button from my JS that they put on their website).  When their user fills out the form on their website, it POSTs to my Rails API.

Comment: your user doesn't have backend but has a server ?

Comment: Doesn't have a server or a back-end.

Comment: then where is your user's website residing ?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, they do have a server but most of my user's just have HTML/CSS and JS websites with content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114790/discussion-between-niceman-and-noah).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's pretend your user's website is www.example.com.

You want to know did this request come from the real www.example.com ? 
There are two possible solutions :

### 1- Certificates

If your user's site uses https(it has a certificate) the certificate identifies a unique site(that what it's for), on signup you can request that certificate and add it to your rails trust store, then in your javascript app you send the certificate on every request and your rails verifies it.

### advantages

1- no backend needed.
2- more secure than a simple api-key, that's because an api-key could provide authentication but not non-repudiation which the certificate provide.
3-easy for your user(provided they already have a certificate).

### disadvantages

1- too secure : you didn't mention that non-repudiation is a goal, if it is this disadvantage doesn't count.
2- might hurt performance : on every request a certificate is posted and verified, not only verifying a certificate is slower than verifying an api-key but sending the certificate on every request may heart bandwidth.
3- requires your user is using https, what if he/she doesn't want to use https for some reason ???

### 2- Setting a proxy

You store the api-key on the server and don't post it in the snippet and you assemble a simple backend that its only job is to send the api-key (some sort of a proxy).

### advantages

1-not too secure : it provides the authentication you want without providing more needless goals.
2- good on performance : yes there is a proxy which may be slower, may be faster but that's faster than verifying a certificate and sending it on every request in my opinion.
3-simpler to program : I think assembling this backend is easier than writing certificate verification code in a Rails app.
4- doesn't require https.

### disadvantages

1-more installation for the user : that's because they have to install a backend besides the include snippet.
2-the form data should be sent to this backend and then to your rails backend, so we have two **round trips**.

Now web servers (Apache,Nginx) can be configured to work as proxies but I don't know if they can be configured to send the api-key too.